# Adding multiple covariates to 'rdplot' in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add multiple covariates to 'rdplot' function that plots a regression discontinuity model in R. Adding just one covariate works fine as follows:

```
rdplot(dataset$CONTINUANCE, 
       dataset$T,
       p=scenario.polynomial_order,
       nbins=c(scenario.bandwidth, scenario.bandwidth),
       kernel=scenario.kernel,
       weights=dataset$USERS,
       h=h,
       covs=cbind(dataset$VIEW_COUNT))
```

...whereas adding multiple covariates does not:

```
rdplot(dataset$CONTINUANCE, 
       dataset$T,
       p=scenario.polynomial_order,
       nbins=c(scenario.bandwidth, scenario.bandwidth),
       kernel=scenario.kernel,
       weights=dataset$USERS,
       h=h,
       covs=cbind(dataset$VIEW_COUNT, dataset$COMMENT_COUNT))
```

Error:

```
Error in crossprod(U_p_l[, colsZ], invG_p_l %*% U_p_l) : 
  non-conformable arguments
Calls: rdplot -> crossprod
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in the 'rdplot' function?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check your variables in your model 1 by 1 to see which one is causing the troubles. In my case, converting the trouble-making variable to numeric did the trick.

Here is the code I used:

```
covs = cbind.data.frame(daily5$bmi, 
        daily5$uni_edu, 
        daily5$married, 
        daily5$worksite, 
        daily5$intervention, 
        daily5$sex, 
        daily5$income, 
        daily5$age, 
        daily5$met_minutes_week_calculated) 

rdrobust::rdplot(daily5$steps, 
        daily5$visit, 
        c = 34, 
        ci = 95, 
        p=4, 
        x.label = "Visit", 
        y.label = "Steps", 
        title = "Regression Discontinuity Plot", 
        covs = covs, 
        covs_eval = "mean" )
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry just to back up my answer here is my code:

```
covs = cbind.data.frame(daily5$bmi, daily5$uni_edu, daily5$married, daily5$worksite, daily5$intervention,
                          daily5$sex, daily5$income, daily5$age, daily5$met_minutes_week_calculated)
  rdrobust::rdplot(daily5$steps,
                   daily5$visit,
                   c = 34,
                   ci = 95, p=4, x.label = "Visit", y.label = "Steps", title = "Regression Discontinuity Plot",
                   covs = covs, covs_eval = "mean" )
```

Comment: Please add this information into the answer you have already posted, so that you have one complete answer instead of 2 partial answers :) You can update your other answer using the ["edit" link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62915026/edit) just underneath that answer.

Comment: FYI I've added this code into your other answer (and formatted it appropriately) for you this time :)